# Grouping by aggregated data

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

Given a table `records` with the columns `id INT`, `status INT`, `startDate DATETIME` and the request to count records per status. How do you count with a correction based on the current date and time?

Imagine the table consists of these records:

| id | status | startDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 <-- In the past |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-05-01 00:00:00 <-- Also in the past |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 <-- This is currently in the future |

The status is actually depending on the date. When the status equals `1` and the date is in the past, the status must be translated to `2`.

So since the status is dependent on the date just counting all the rows and grouping by the status is not accurate.

To generate a dataset for a graph, I need to have a count of all actual statuses, grouped by status.

#### Example of what will not work

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 1 AND dateStart < CURRENT_DATE() THEN 2 ELSE status END) as count,
  status
FROM records
group by status
```

This provides the following result:

| count | status |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

This might seem ok at first glance, but it does not count correctly because the grouping is on the column `status` so the `CASE WHEN..` statement is pretty much ignored.

The result I'm expecting would be this:

| count | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

Since there are two records with status 1 but one of these records has a date in the past it should be corrected to two.

#### Limitations

1. We cannot change the table or the columns.
2. We cannot use subqueries and can only provide columns or expressions in the `select`, `where` and `group by` parts of the query.
3. We cannot update the table.

Comment: *When the status equals 1 and the date is in the past, the status must be translated to 2.* 1 and 2 are the only values in `status` column?

Comment: @Akina for the sake of the example, only these two statuses matter. There are, however two more statuses that - like status 2 - do not need any correction.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `CASE` expression to get the correct `status` and group by that:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN status = 1 AND startDate < CURRENT_DATE() THEN 2 ELSE status END AS correct_status,
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM records
GROUP BY correct_status
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69b9dbbfa50613e5f801688fb1fdb67e).